GetX5 animation played only once when widget is built first time
I am trying to animate the button using simplified animation from the GetX (5.0-release-candidate-9) package.
The problem is that the animation method is called only once when the page is loaded, but never called on tap.
Here is the code:
class SettingsView extends GetView<SettingsController> {
  const SettingsView({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SettingsView'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ValueBuilder<bool>(
            initialValue: false,
            builder: (isChecked, updateFn) {
              print('rebuild performed');
              return OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('pressed ');
                        updateFn(true);
                      },
                      child: Text('Press me'))
                  .scale(
                  begin: 0.9,
                  end: 1,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  // isSequential: true,
                  onComplete: (animationController) {
                    animationController.reset();
                    //animationController.reverse();
                    print('animation completed');
                    //animationController.forward();
                    //   animationController.fling();
                    //   animationController.stop();
                    //animationController.dispose();
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

